# SQL / Python Create Table Error

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am getting a strange error when I am trying to create this table.... When I track it back I have nothing on line 5? Can anyone help me on how to track this error?

import settings
import mysql.connector
from database import login_info
import datetime as dt

```
def main():
    db = mysql.connector.Connect(**login_info)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql =('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS messages')
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()

message_table = """\
    CREATE TABLE messages(
        msgID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        message VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,
        subject VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,
       )"""
cursor.execute(message_table)
db.commit()
```

Error ==
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 5

I can connect ot SQl in an interactive window no problem.

Comment: You may have a further problem after the one you're currently experiencing due to the brackets round ('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS messages')

Comment: Syntax error: The comma after the last field definition. The comma is meant to separate the elements of the definition of the table (fields, indexes, etc)... Please always remember to check the documentation (in this case, MySQL documentation: Data Definition Statements: CREATE). The error message even gives you a good hint about where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `,` at the end of line 4.

Comment: After the last NULL. I don't think you are permitted to have a trailing `,` after the last field declaration.